# Oracle job to run daily in Oracle Express edition 11g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, jobs

![enter image description here][1]

I just updated with a new version of the database. I've previously used Oracle database versioyon 10. Now I installed Oracle 11g Express edition.

I had the three jobs on the DBMS_jobs.

I programmed it to run them at a particular time on a daily basis. every day at 01:00 in the stored procedure was running on a regular basis.

```
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
  what => 'BEGIN CALL_MY_SP; END;',
  next_date => to_date('24-09-2013 01:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
   interval => 'TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) + 1/24');
  commit;
end;
```

Although the same job to the new Oracle database running. But this job is manually executing.

How do I run automatically on a regular basis every day? But What if I did not!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rePVq.png

your job

http://l1309.hizliresim.com/1f/s/sz6pg.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run manually, try:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('MY_JOB',false);
```

and to stop manually, use:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.stop_job('MY_JOB',false);
```

If your question is how to scheduler a job in Oracle, its a big topic (see [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) ), but a simple example would be:

```
BEGIN

  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name=>'JOB_TEST2',
    job_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action=>'BEGIN
    dbms_lock.sleep(10);
    END;',
    start_date=>systimestamp,
    repeat_interval=>'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1',
    number_of_arguments=>0,
    enabled=>TRUE,
    comments=>'Job duration is 10 seconds, launches every minute'
  );

END;
```

Since it was created as enabled, it will start running automatically.  You can verify this looking at the logs (dba_scheduler_job_run_details) and can view basic attributes via dba_scheduler_jobs

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but your post said: "But I'm trying to manually executing. How do I run this job on oracle oracle 11g express edition?"

Comment: I would like to run automatically on a regular basis

Comment: btw @ant , you should use dbms_scheduler for scheduled jobs.  But again, perhaps I misunderstand your question

Comment: @ant what error exactly?  did you create a scheduler job like my example?

Comment: yes... i drop my job after run above your job . i change only this 'dbms_lock.sleep(10);' to CALL_MY_SP; .

Comment: I have described the first time I removed all the job.  after run above your job... (only change this line  dbms_lock.sleep(10); to SP_GUNCETELEME;.... and finally I'm trying to run the job manually. I get the error above. No other error. job work also be automatically http://l1309.hizliresim.com/1f/s/sz6pg.png

Comment: @ant I just needed the ora code (27492).  There are several possible reasons, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898444/oracle-enterprise-manager-job-is-hung) for more info.

Comment: solved the problem, this leads to. `alter system set job_queue_processes = 10;`